# Evolution Mail Client

Tags: evolution, client

why I am not able to setup my Google account with the client. I have done all the IMAP/POP forwarding from my google account.

ScreenShot is also attached:

[image]

Comment: Do you two step authentication setup... if so you might create an app password for evolution to side step or skip two step authentication...

Comment: I din't do any thing which asks for two-step verification etc...

Comment: I mean on your google side!

Comment: Thanks George !!
But i didn't do any thing regarding the 2 step verification on google side.
Still facing the same prblm..
Also not able to use Thunderbird client :(

Comment: With thunderbird i am not able to configure at all. It is showing incorrect username password.. though i have tried many times with my personal password after login to gmail also.